# How do I make Kubuntu see Bluetooth?

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I am on Kubuntu 18.04, and I want to connect a couple Wiimotes. I have enabled Bluetooth in the BIOS, and I have made sure that my computer had it turned on in the first place. So then in the terminal, I typed `lswm`, to start the pairing and it said:

```
No Bluetooth interface found
```

So in the Bluetooth settings, I tried to go into the settings, and this is all I got:

[image: Bluetooth error]

I am on Plasma 5.12 with the Oxygen theme, And a Dell Latitude Laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.